# Declare a map of <String, List<CustomClass>> in spring application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I spent some time to externalize some configuration but unable to figure out a way to do so.

My use case :

```
class DocumentValidationMetaData {

private String docType;
private boolean isMandatory;

}
```

```
@PropertySource (""classpath:*documentValidation.properties)
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class DocumentValidationConfig{

   @NotNull
   Map<String, List<DocumentValidationMetaData>> config

}
```

how can I declare this config in my properties file ?

Thanks in advance,
Ayushi

Answer (score 0):

You can Autowire the Environment class and retrieve the value from the documentation.properties file.

If you have a configuration file for example :

myapp.properties

> app.url=1.2.3.4

Then you can use you properties as below :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "<your base package>" })
@PropertySource("classpath:myapp.properties")    
public class MyAppClass {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public String myTestMethod() throws Exception {

        String url = env.getProperty("app.url");
        return url; 
}
```

Correct the "" inside your `@PropertySource` declaration :

```
 @PropertySource ("classpath:*documentValidation.properties")
```